# Difference between WatchKit App and Watch App in Apple's Lister sample app

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

Lister, Apple's sample app to demonstrate WatchOS, shows a `WatchKit App` as well as a `Watch App` among the available targets. What's the difference between two?

From what I understood of WatchOS 2, the iPhone app contains a WatchApp which contains contains the resources and interfaces that run on the Watch itself as well as the WatchKit extension, which has the code and interfaces that get executed on the Watch.
[image]

I don't understand the reason for the two different targets existing.

I've viewed Watchkit In Depth part 1 & 2 WWDC 2015 videos, among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First One is for WatchOS1.
The other is for WatchOS2.

Each extension can have own deployment target.

WatchOS2 App has to complied for different architecture because the watchOS2 apps are running on watch itself. However, WatchOS1 App runs on iPhone. So targets have to be separated.